# Update Azure AD Application keys or secrets using Microsoft Graph API - BadRequest Error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, beta

I am trying to patch password credentials for an application using Microsoft Graph API beta endpoint for application resource type.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{applicationId}
```

The content variable is a JSON-serialized representation of something like this:

```
[{
"customKeyIdentifier":null,
"endDateTime":"2019-11-19T23:16:24.2602448Z",
"keyId":"47fde652-8b60-4384-b630-8e5f8f6e24b1",
"startDateTime":"2018-11-19T23:16:24.2602448Z",
"secretText":"SomeGeneratedPassword",
"hint":null
}]
```

Calling code is this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authHeaderValue.Result.AccessToken);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                    .Accept
                    .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
                var requestUri = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{applicationId}";
                var content = GeneratePasswordCredentials(passwordHint);
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(
                        content,
                        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                        "application/json")
                };
                request.Headers
                    .Accept
                    .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var resultApi = await client.SendAsync(request);
                response = await resultApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

Auth appears to be working fine, but the response is this (inner error removed for brevity):

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Empty Payload. JSON content expected.",
  }
}
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with JSON string specified for Update Application Microsoft Graph API. It's missing which property you're trying to update for the application. I've added "passwordCredentials" property and given it the JSON as a collection. See jsonContent variable at the very beginning of my code.

```
/*Only change here from original JSON is to add the passwordCredentials node*/

{
  "passwordCredentials":[
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": null,
      "endDateTime": "2019-11-19T23:16:24.2602448Z",
      "keyId": "47fde652-8b60-4384-b630-8e5f8f6e24b1",
      "startDateTime": "2018-11-19T23:16:24.2602448Z",
      "secretText": "SomeGeneratedPassword",
      "hint": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I started with your code and the 400 bad response error reproduced for me as well.

Below is the final working code and now I get back a 204 response status. I can also see the new key added to Application keys collection from Azure Portal > App Registrations > My app > Settings > Keys

```
string jsonContent = "{\"passwordCredentials\":[{\"customKeyIdentifier\":null,\"endDateTime\":\"2019-11-19T23:16:24.2602448Z\",\"keyId\":\"47fde652-8b60-4384-b630-8e5f8f6e24b1\",\"startDateTime\":\"2018-11-19T23:16:24.2602448Z\",\"secretText\":\"somegeneratedpassword\",\"hint\":null}]}";

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authHeaderValue.Result.AccessToken);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                    .Accept
                    .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
    var requestUri = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{applicationId}";

    // I have commented out this method and passed in my JSON instead.   
    //var content = GeneratePasswordCredentials(passwordHint);
    var content = jsonContent;
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
    {
                    Content = new StringContent(
                        content,
                        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                        "application/json")
    };

    request.Headers
                    .Accept
                    .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var resultApi = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    //response = await resultApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var response = resultApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Comment: The problem with this seems to be that it does not allow adding to the collection of `passwordCredentials` - it overwrites them. How can you append a _new_ `passwordCredential` to the array? (Like adding a Secret in via the Portal.)

Answer (score 0):

The body content format should be

```
{
  "passwordCredentials":
    [
      {"customKeyIdentifier":"YWJjZA==",
      "startDateTime":"2018-11-20T02:37:07.3963006Z",
      "endDateTime":"2019-11-20T02:37:07.3963006Z",
      "secretText":"The passwords must be 16-64 characters in length",
      "keyId":"aeda515d-dc58-4ce6-a452-3bc3d84f58a3",
      "hint":"xxx"}
    ]
}
```

The following the demo code to Generate PasswordCredentials body content

```
public static string GeneratePasswordCredentials(string passwordHint)
   {
         var passwordCredential = new JObject
         {
                new JProperty("customKeyIdentifier",Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordHint)),
                new JProperty("startDateTime",DateTime.UtcNow),
                new JProperty("endDateTime", DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1)),
                new JProperty("secretText", "The passwords must be 16-64 characters in length"),
                new JProperty("keyId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new JProperty("hint", passwordHint)
         };
         JArray jArray = new JArray
         {
              passwordCredential
         };
         var jsonObject = new JObject
         {
              new JProperty("passwordCredentials",jArray)
         };

         var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
         return json;
     }
```

**Note**: The  request url should be `$"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{ApplicationObjectId}"`